# Warning 7 Validation (XHTML5): The values permitted for this attribute do not include 'get'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form element, for example

```
<form class="shrinkwrap" method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Details", "Subcontractor", new { id = Model.CompanyId })">
```

and when I build my application I get the above warning.
I ignore it as it doesn't make any difference. But why do I get this warning in the first place?
My Google search does not show up anything.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be lowercase, see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-method):

> The method and formmethod content attributes are enumerated attributes with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword get, mapping to the state GET, indicating the HTTP GET method.
> - The keyword post, mapping to the state POST, indicating the HTTP POST method.

But you don't even need to specify it in your case, because:

> The missing value default for these attributes is the GET state.

Comment: I get the same message for lower case